# Replace the text in a html tag

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

the HTML code is:

```
<pre>
  <span class="cm-tab"></span>
  <span class="cm-tab"></span>
  "widgetId" : "123",
</pre>
```

I need to replace the value 123 with 4b22a0f8-9047-4fd9-8330-d6fa7c85e90c

I tried the following code:

```
driver
  .findElement(By.xpath("//pre[contains(@text(),'\"123\"')]"))
    .sendKeys("4b22a0f8-9047-4fd9-8330-d6fa7c85e90c");
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? When do need it replaced? The way you have the question worded the answer would be `<pre> <span class="cm-tab">   </span><span class="cm-tab">    </span>"widgetId" : "4b22a0f8-9047-4fd9-8330-d6fa7c85e90c", </pre>`

Comment: That's the exact output i need. i am using selenium.

Comment: OK you tried the code shown. What happened when you tried that?

Comment: I don't think this approach will work. You can't type in a `<pre>` element on a web page; only in an `<input>` or similar element. Therefore using `sendKeys()` on a `<pre>` element is unlikely to insert any text.